# What is the diffrence between website and web application?

Tags: web-applications, web

I read a lot of IT books but I have mixed between Web application and Website.

Is that two words are same?
If no can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website is an umbrella term, you can make simple websites with nothing but HTML in Notepad that do nothing more than show pages like an online poster for a sale. When you start talking applications, that's when you're talking about adding extra functions with additional languages like C# and JavaScript. So in a way, you can say all web apps are web sites, but not all sites are apps.